# Zend Framework 1.11: how to autoload a class that uses namespaces

Tags: zend-framework, namespaces, autoload

I have a Zend Framework 1.11 application, and I want to use a package called [RandomLib](https://github.com/ircmaxell/RandomLib). The problem is, it doesn't have an autoloader, and I've tried reading the Zend documentation on using autoloaders, but I can't make sense of it.

I've placed the RandomLib folder in my library directory. What kind of code would I need in my Bootstrap.php file to autoload the class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Starting in version 1.10.0, Zend Framework now allows loading classes from PHP namespaces. This support follows the same guidelines and implementation as that found in the » PHP Framework Interop Group PSR-0 reference implementation.* [Source](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.loader.autoloader.html)

1. Put content of `RandomLib/lib` under `library/RandomLib`
2. In `application.ini` add `autoloaderNamespaces[] = "RandomLib"`

Answer (score 0):

If you wish you can include namespace libraries directly in your Bootstrap.php file after you moved the library in "library/MyExternalLib"

```
protected function _initAutoLoader()
{
    $loader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
    $loader->registerNamespace('MyExternalLib');
    return $loader;
}
```